# If I do a program in C # with the SharpDevelop........?

Tags: software, licensing

If I do a program in C # with the SharpDevelop 5.1 IDE under what license would the program be submitted? can I sell it or use it in a private company?

Comment: Such a program would be yours to license as you please.  Why would you think otherwise?

Answer (score 3):

If you develop a program yourself and it wasn't a work made for hire, then the program is yours to do with as you please. You hold the copyright to it.

Many developers choose existing licencing arrangements or they can choose to create a license on their own, or using an attorney. And sometimes they choose to release their programs into the public domain. If you release it into the public domain, you are essentially giving up your copyright.

The IDE (Integrated Development Environment) you used to develop your program does not dictate what licenses you can use.

There are some existing licenses that others use (which you are free to use or NOT to use) give varying protections to you regarding what you are allowing others to do; right of others to copy, right of others to modify, right of others to distribute, rights to sub-licence, and so on.

One of the licensing schemes is the GNU General Public License (GPL). But there are many others, too many to list here.